# Firestore REST API database listening

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Do you know how to setup Firestore listening using REST API. This is my attempt:

```
url: "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project_name/databases/(default)/documents:listen"
headers: {["Content-Type"] = "application/json"}

body: "{"addTarget": { 
            "once" : false, 
            "documents" : { 
                    "documents" : [ "projects/project_name/databases/(default)/documents/Users/USER_DOC_ID" ]
                        }
            }}"

Request verb: POST
```

And the response:

```
  [{
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Invalid value (Object), ",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
          "fieldViolations": [
            {
              "description": "Invalid value (Object), "
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ]
```

Most propably, my request body is invalid. I used this reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/firestore/v1beta1/projects.databases/listen

How is the body should look like?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am a google group and now I was told that this function does not work. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss

Comment: according to his document, there is not related restful api to streaming the update of data

Comment: Can some body post example how listen to changes ? or can ask google to remove the page https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.listen

Comment: Does REST api support this in 2021? Or still no luck?

Answer (score 2):

The listen method is not available through the REST API. It is available through the [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1beta1#google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore.Listen).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Why doesn't the REST API support listeners? The RPC documentation is very vague too.