# FireStore listen does not work in APIS Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203039/firestore-rest-api-database-listening) post I understand that FireStore does not support listen in REST API, but on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.listen) it still exist.
When trying to use the APIS Explorer I get 400 error code.

Doesn't the APIS Explorer know how to handle the request (RPC request) or this feature does not work and need to be removed.
 [image]
[image]

If it does I will be happy for some examples how to use it (prefer in dart).

Answer (score 1):

This a bug in the API explorer and should be removed. As you pointed out, the Listen method is not available in the REST API.