# Is there any way to get realtime updates from Firebase Firestore REST API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a chip that has internet connectivity that I am programming using C language. I am able to make http requests using this language, so I thought that the Firestore REST API would save me. Unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to get live changes from the REST API. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no public API to get realtime updates from Firestore over its REST API. See the [reference docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#get) for a list of available operations.

Also see:

- [Firestore REST API database listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203039/firestore-rest-api-database-listening), which mentions that you *can* get this behavior through the RPC API.

Comment: I saw this StackOverflow post before, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it. Could you give me an example http request that I can make to this rpc api to listen to a document change? What is the url, what are the headers? I'm sorry for being a noob. Thank you

Comment: I really don't understand what the difference between the REST API and the RPC API is. when I do a post to the following url using postman: https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/databases/(default)/documents:commit, am I using the REST API or the RPC API?

Comment: That's a REST call. gRPC is a protocol on top of that.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how to call that (g)RPC API differently though. I only learned about it when I searched and found Juan's answer to the question I linked.

Comment: Oh ok. Any ideas how we can find a solution to this problem?